# Conditional color scheme in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

In my workflow, I manage two sets of code per website project.  One is for live code and the other is for code which is still being staged.

I would like for live files & staging files to be styled by different color schemes so that I can easily differentiate them.

Is there a way to change the color scheme in Sublime Text based on a file's directory path?

---

**For example:**

- `/live/style.css` is styled with `Packages/ColorSchemes/ColorScheme_1.tmTheme`
- `/staging/style.css` is styled with `Packages/ColorSchemes/ColorScheme_2.tmTheme`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple plugin that met your initial requirements and then ended up adding a few extra features since it could be useful to others as a release.

---

The plugin utilizes `RegEx` to allow matching of:

- FileNames ( *full & partial* )
- Extensions
- Parent Directories
- SubDirectory Structures

---

#### Some Examples:

[image: Path]

[image: FileName]

---

Get the plugin:

## [@ PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Conditional%20ColorSchemes)

## [@ GitHub](https://github.com/Enteleform/ST_ConditionalColorSchemes)